# webapi 2.0 as a sub application

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I have an MVC website project, and a webapi project.

The MVC website is hosted at site.com
The WebApi is hosting in a virtual application(not a virtual directory) in /api so: site.com/api

My problem is that the actual configuration of the webapi is never actually taken into account. Whatever i put in GlobalConfig or app_start or a startup file (IAppBuilder) is not taken into account at all.

For a simple example, I created a basic Filter (from System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute) and configured it using GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new myfilter);

The filter is never called. It works fine if I put the filter directly on one of the api controllers, then it gets called.

Is this normal behavior? shouldn't an application be self contained? Right now it seems to be taking the parent MVC projet's configs....

How can I configure the /api application with its own settings?